# Colour background of JPanel from different class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Trying to change the background colour of my JPanel from a different class using a variable. Why is this giving me an error? (Really new to java, sorry...)

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class window {

    public window(int x, int y, boolean isVisible, boolean isResizable, Color col){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        int xSize = x;
        int ySize = y;
        jframe.setSize(xSize, ySize);
        jframe.setVisible(isVisible);
        jframe.setResizable(isResizable);

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jpanel.setSize(xSize - 100, ySize - 100);
        jpanel.setOpaque(true);
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.col);  
        jpanel.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

My main class does this:

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class design {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window window1 = new window(400, 200, true, true, Color.green);
        window window2 = new window(1000, 720, true, true, Color.red);
    }

}
```

The error it is giving me is 'col cannot be resolved to a field'. Which I know means that it doesn't understand what col is doing there but that's what I'm confused by because I've declared it as a colour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You refer to the variable get from the constructor.

Just change the `jpanel.setBackground(Color.col);` to:

```
jpanel.setBackground(col);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I understand as well. I will accept the answer when the timer runs out, you were too quick ;). Just out of curiosity, what do you think of my code? Am I using classes correctly and efficiently?

Comment: First according the Java conventions, you should name the class with a capital letter (`Window`). Then the `Window` class should `extend JFrame` or at least have it as a private field accesed with getters/setters. There is no general way how to write a code, so you have to try it yourself and get experience with a practice :)

Comment: Okay yes, my bad with the capitals because I did know that... Why should the window class extend JFrame? Isn't it already part of it because it's imported?

Comment: Because the `Window` class works only with the `JFrame`, so why not to extend it for better approach and work with it?